# Similar to .sh on Windows 7

Tags: shell, batch-file, util.cmd

I'm used to using a Mac, and I've written a program for my Mac that I now need to implement on a PC. On a mac, I run it through a shell file, using the following code:

```
cd ./desktop/Program
./MyProgram
./clearFiles
```

I've tried entering

```
cd ./desktop/Program^
./MyProgram^
./clearFiles
```

and saving it as both a .bat and a .cmd file but I can't get either to work. Is there a similar format to .sh I could use on Windows 7 to do the same thing? I want to be able to execute 3 commands in Command Prompt with just one click.

Comment: What's with the caret? A .bat file  should work fine even with just regular line endings between the commands (though the semantics of e.g. `cd` are different than on U*x).

Comment: syntax is different when you do cmd batch files, also the folder structure

Comment: When I don't include the carets, the .bat file only executes the first command and then quits (An answer to a similar question suggested the carets, but I couldn't get it to work). I want the .bat file to execute all three of those commands.

Comment: you might want to review Window 7 directory structure: http://www.informatics.buzdo.com/p737-windows-7-folders-files.htm

Comment: Do you want to learn [tag:batch] or want to use [tag:unix] on windows enviroment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft offers a [command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands).

It looks like you want to set current directory to a subdirectory on desktop of user containing your applications `MyProgram` and `clearFiles` which are called one after the other.

A batch file to do this would be:

```
cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Program"
MyProgram.exe
clearFiles.exe
```

As a single line the command line would be:

```
cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Program" & MyProgram.exe & clearFiles.exe
```

See [Conditional Execution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) on [SS64](https://ss64.com/) containing even more information than provided by Microsoft about command processor of Windows.

Opening on Windows a command prompt window and executing `help` shows a list of commands. Running a command like **cd** with parameter `/?` in command prompt window results in getting help for this command displayed which can be multiple display pages like for commands **for** or **set**.

`%USERPROFILE%` references the environment variable `USERPROFILE` containing path to user profiles directory (home directory of user on *nix).